# In R: How can I know if my packages are up to date?

Tags: function, r, package

I am looking for a function that will tell me, for a list of packages, which of them is up to date and which is not (I need it so to trace back an R crash).

Thanks,

Tal

Comment: R packages (sorry if it wasn't clear)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you could just update them with the `update.packages()` function.

You could use `installed.packages()` and `available.packages()` to find any differences.  Just merge the two results together on the name, and then look for version differences.

```
i <- installed.packages()
a <- available.packages()
ia <- merge(i, a, by="Package")[,c("Package", "Version.x", "Version.y")]
ia[as.character(ia$Version.x) != as.character(ia$Version.y),]
```

Comment: And that 'comparison by sets' is basically what CRANberries does to compute new or changes packages.

Comment: `old.packages` will list the out of date ones.

Answer (score 1):

`updateme` is a really handy [package](https://github.com/wurli/updateme) that indicates if a new package version is available:

```
# install.packages("updateme")
library(updateme)
library(tidyverse) # check if there any new versions of tidyverse packages available
```

[image]