# Using rpy2 to check if I have the latest version of an R package installed

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have the following method that checks whether an R package is installed. This helps me avoid installing the package every time I run the code.

I want to add functionality so we can check if the R package is installed **AND** if it's the latest version. I've had a look at the rpy2 documentation though and I can't see a way to do this.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how I can achieve this? Cheers

```
    def get_source_package(self, package_name):
        
        # Check if R package is installed. If it is installed, import it
        if packages.isinstalled(package_name):
            self.source_package = packages.importr(package_name)
            return self.source_package

        # Check if R package is installed. If not, install and then import it
        else:
            utils = packages.importr('utils')
            utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
            utils.install_packages(package_name)
            self.source_package = packages.importr(package_name)
            return self.source_package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two other functions available in `utils` to get versions of installed and available packages and compare the two to get an answer. The relevant R code is provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563683, which can be translated to Python as below:

```py
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

utils = importr('utils')

def extract_versions(package_data):
    return dict(zip(
        package_data.rx(True, 'Package'),  # get Package column
        package_data.rx(True, 'Version')   # get Version column
    ))


i = extract_versions(utils.installed_packages())
a = extract_versions(utils.available_packages())

package_name = 'ggplot2'

is_latest_version = i[package_name] == a[package_name]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought there might have been something in the utils package but couldn't find anything. I am currently using GET requests to the package's repo on Github, but I'm going to try this solution instead as it's a lot cleaner and exactly what I was after. Thanks again!